# Need help in connecting Connections in a class

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have created a window with QTableWidget having a cell with 2 buttons.

Buttons are created in seperate class where i am passing QTableWidget instance from main procedure.

I am not able to get the button events, which are connected in button Creation class. My code snippet is as below

```
class Buttons():

    def __init__(self,tab):

        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.saveButtonItem = QtGui.QPushButton('Save')
        self.deleteButtonItem = QtGui.QPushButton('Delete')

        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.saveButtonItem)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.deleteButtonItem)

        cellWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        cellWidget.setLayout(buttonLayout)

        tab.insertRow(tab.rowCount())

        tab.setCellWidget(tab.rowCount() - 1,0,cellWidget)

        self.setconncection()

    def setconncection(self):

        self.saveButtonItem.clicked.connect(self.btnSaveClicked)
        self.deleteButtonItem.clicked.connect(self.btnDeleteClicked)
        print 'connections are set'

    def btnSaveClicked(self):

        print 'save clicked'

    def btnDeleteClicked(self):

        print 'delete clicked'

class testing(QtGui.QTableWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super(testing,self).__init__()

        self.setColumnCount(1)

        for i in xrange(3):

            self.r = Buttons(self)

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication (sys.argv)

    win = testing ()
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My window at run time is as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `__init__` of testing, the reference to Buttons instance is lost and the object is destroyed. (Variable `r` is affected but not used.)

Keeping a link to it (see last line in following code snippet) makes it work.

```
class testing(QtGui.QTableWidget):

def __init__(self):

        super(testing,self).__init__()

        self.setColumnCount(1)
        self.setRowCount(1)

        self.buttons = []
        for i in xrange(3):
            self.buttons.append(Buttons(self))
```

Comment: actually i am adding n no.of rows dynamically. at that time only last row is having links as per ur suggestions. I have updated the question for exact requirement.

Comment: Obviously, you need to keep a link to all buttons. Answer updated.

Comment: Perfect, I tried adding all instances to list as in ur answer, but i added without self. Yhx for the solution